# How to sum and count specific keys in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following collection that contains the arrays below:

```
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => array:13 [▼

      "label" => "00000000-N/A"
      "views" => 980
      "clicks" => 444
      "form_submissions_perc" => "100.0"

    ]
    1 => array:13 [▼

      "label" => "1111-N/A"
      "views" => 323
      "clicks" => 1009
      "form_submissions_perc" => "100.0"

    ]
  ]
```

I am trying to sum clicks and average views but in my try I get the wrong data:

```
   $sum = 0;

    foreach ($data as $k => $subArray) {

        foreach ($subArray as $id => $value) {

            $sum += $subArray['views'];
        }

    }

    dd($sum);
```

This was my try to sum but didnt get the right results

Desired output

```
   array:2 [

       "views"=> 1303,
       "clicks"=> 1451

    ]
```

Comment: There is no `total_income` key in those arrays...

Comment: `"views"=> array_sum(array_column($data, 'views')),`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$sum` as array and get correct value of multiarray:

```
$sum = array(
       'clicks' => 0,
       'views' => 0
       );

foreach ($data as $id => $value) {
    $sum['clicks'] += $value['clicks'];
    $sum['views'] += $value['views'];
}

dd($sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   foreach ($data as $k => $subArray) {
        $valueSum[] = $subArray['views'];
        $clickSum[] = $subArray['clicks'];
    }
    echo array_sum($valueSum);
    echo array_sum($clickSum);
```

this is also a clean and easy way .

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = [
            [
                "label"                 => "00000000-N/A",
                "views"                 => 980,
                "clicks"                => 444,
                "form_submissions_perc" => "100.0"
            ],
            [
                "label"                 => "1111-N/A",
                "views"                 => 323,
                "clicks"                => 1009,
                "form_submissions_perc" => "100.0"
            ]
        ];

        $result['views']  = array_sum( array_column( $data, 'views' ) );
        $result['clicks'] = array_sum( array_column( $data, 'clicks' ) );

        dd( $result );
```

This is the easiest way to do your work.

Result:

```
Array ( [views] => 1303 [clicks] => 1453 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**array_reduce**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) instead

```
$data = array_reduce($array, function ($old, $new) {
    return [
        "view" => $old["view"] + $new["view"],
        "clicks" => $old["clicks"] + $new["clicks"]
    ];
}, ["view" => 0, "clicks" => 0]);

print '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```